# Rails CORS can't prevent layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cors

I have implemented CORS in a Rails 4 app using the rack-cors gem. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox but I can't prevent the layout from being rendered.

At the end of my action I have the following:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { layout false if request.xhr? }
end
```

If I put format.js or format.json before format.html then it doesn't work any more. request.xhr? returns false. I am guessing that this is because cors redirects the request and it is no longer seem as an xhr request?

The only way I can think of to do this would be to copy the action to another name or another controller and disable the layout completely but that seems too hacky.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by installing the rack_cors gem and creating a new controller named Ajax just for the cors request. As the action was identical to the regular html action in another controller, I moved the code over to a module so both controllers could share it. The only difference between the controllers was that I set

```
layout false
```

at the top of the new controller. Here is my complete controller.

```
class AjaxController < ApplicationController

include CalcResults

skip_before_filter :authorize

layout false

def ajax_results

  calc_results

  respond_to do |format|

    format.html 

  end
 end
end
```

In my config/application.rb file:

```
config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '/ajax_results/*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :options]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:-

```
format.html { :layout => false if request.xhr? }
```

Comment: When I do that it breaks cors and I get an error Origin http://localhost:8000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: Yet if I put layout false at the top of the controller it works with no layout.

Comment: The only way to make this work is to copy the action I need for cors to another controller and set layout false for the new controller. Not exactly dry but it works.